# Using keras tuner for hyperparameter tuning and extracting trial statistics with Tensorboard workaround

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard, keras-tuner

I'm using keras tuner for hyperparameter tuning my sequential neural network in keras. My aim is to let keras tuner do a lot of trials and then save all statistics - loss, hyperparameters, trial numbers and epochs -  to a file, so I can plot them myself and get a better overview over how keras tuner conducted the tests. Note that this is a regression, so I'm using mean squared error (mse) as a loss function, not accuracy. Here's an example of my network and the setup of keras tuner (based on the ["Getting started" tutorial of keras tuner](https://keras.io/guides/keras_tuner/getting_started/)):

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import keras_tuner
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorboard.backend.event_processing import event_accumulator

# generate random data
random_data = np.random.rand(100,4)
x_data = random_data[:, :-1]
y_data = random_data[:, -1:]
input_dimensions = len(x_data[0, :])
# split data into train and test
x_train, x_eval, y_train, y_eval = train_test_split(x_data, y_data, test_size=0.3, random_state=101)

# create keras tuner and model
def build_model(hp):
    model = keras.Sequential()
    # test number of layers, number of neurons in each layer and activation function
    for i in range(hp.Int("num_layers", 2, 4)):
        model.add(layers.Dense(
                units=hp.Int(f"units_{i}", min_value=32, max_value=1024, step=32),
                activation=hp.Choice("activation", ["relu", "sigmoid"])))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation="linear"))
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0005), 
                  loss='mse')

    return model

build_model(keras_tuner.HyperParameters())

tuner = keras_tuner.RandomSearch(
    hypermodel=build_model, 
    objective=keras_tuner.Objective('loss', direction="min"), 
    max_trials=5,
    executions_per_trial=3, 
    overwrite=True, 
    project_name="keras_tuner_test")
```

For extracting the statistics I'm using the Tensorboard callback method (just to be clear: I don't want to actually use Tensorboard. I want only the data and then decide for myself how to display it) with the following code based on [this link](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-tuner/issues/271) or [this link](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-tuner/issues/120):

```
sample_log_directory = <path to directory>

tensorboard_callback = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=sample_log_directory)
tuner.search(x_train, y_train, epochs=3, validation_data=(x_eval, y_eval), callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])

def extract_history(best_trial):
    acc = []
    val_acc = []
    loss = []
    val_loss = []

    for set_data in ['train', 'validation']:
        if set_data == 'train':
            print(sample_log_directory + best_trial + '/execution0/' + set_data)
            ea = event_accumulator.EventAccumulator(sample_log_directory + best_trial + '/execution0/' + set_data)
            ea.Reload()
                            
            for i in range(len(ea.Scalars('epoch_loss'))):
                acc.append(ea.Scalars('epoch_acc')[i][2])
                loss.append(ea.Scalars('epoch_loss')[i][2])
                #lr.append(ea.Scalars('epoch_lr')[i][2])
    
        if set_data == 'validation':
            ea = event_accumulator.EventAccumulator(sample_log_directory  + best_trial + '/execution0/' + set_data)
            ea.Reload()
            for i in range(len(ea.Scalars('epoch_loss'))):
                val_acc.append(ea.Scalars('epoch_acc')[i][2])
                val_loss.append(ea.Scalars('epoch_loss')[i][2])

    return acc, val_acc, loss, val_loss

best_trial = tuner.oracle.get_best_trials()[0].trial_id
acc, val_acc, loss, val_loss = extract_history(best_trial)
```

Unfortunately, when doing that I get the error message `KeyError: 'Key epoch_loss was not found in Reservoir'`. It seems like with e.g. ea.Scalars('epoch_acc') I merely have the wrong key (as I said at the beginning, this is a regression and therefore not using accuracy). How can I find out which keys are correct? I tried inspecting `ea.scalars.Keys()` which results in an empty list, although it seems that `ea.scalars` is not the same as `ea.Scalars`.

Answer (score 2):

I recently bumped into this issue with saving and plot trial history metrics, so I made this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Arkaikus/67b4492bf420680e117b7bd439e980bd) to extend kerastuner randomsearch, save metrics and plot them at the end of each trial. You can also plot the best models in a single plot, here's the code hope it helps

```py
import os
import json
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from kerastuner.tuners import RandomSearch as _RandomSearch
from kerastuner.engine.trial import Trial


class RandomSearch(_RandomSearch):
    histories = {}

    def on_epoch_end(self, trial, model, epoch, logs=None):
        trial_id = trial.trial_id
        trial_history = self.histories.setdefault(trial_id, {})
        for metric, value in logs.items():
            trial_history.setdefault(metric, []).append(value)

    def on_trial_end(self, trial):
        super().on_trial_end(trial)

        self.plot_and_save_history(trial)

    def plot_and_save_history(self, trial: Trial):
        # this will save a plot of the trial training metrics by step in each train folder, it'll also save the metrics as a .json
        trial_id = trial.trial_id
        trial_history = self.histories[trial_id]

        # Create directory for trial if it doesn't exist
        trial_dir = self.get_trial_dir(trial_id)
        os.makedirs(trial_dir, exist_ok=True)

        plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))  # Create a larger figure

        for metric_name, metric_values in trial_history.items():
            plt.plot(metric_values, label=metric_name)  # Add label for legend

        plt.title("Metrics History")
        plt.xlabel("Step")
        plt.ylabel("Value")
        plt.legend()  # Add legend
        plt.savefig(os.path.join(trial_dir, "metrics.png"))
        plt.close()

        # Save history to JSON file
        history_file = os.path.join(trial_dir, "history.json")
        with open(history_file, "w") as f:
            json.dump(trial_history, f, indent=4)

    def plot_best_trials(self, num_models, wrap_columns=4, smooth_factor=0.5, suffix=""):
        # this will retrieve the best trials, load the saved metrics and plot them in a single plot
        best_trials = self.oracle.get_best_trials(num_models)
        num_trials = len(best_trials)

        rows = (num_trials - 1) // wrap_columns + 1
        cols = min(num_trials, wrap_columns)

        fig, axes = plt.subplots(rows, cols, figsize=(20, 5))
        # fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4)
        # fig.tight_layout()

        for i, trial in enumerate(best_trials):
            trial_id = trial.trial_id
            trial_dir = self.get_trial_dir(trial_id)
            history_file = os.path.join(trial_dir, "history.json")

            with open(history_file, "r") as f:
                trial_history = json.load(f)

            ax = axes[i // cols, i % cols] if rows > 1 else axes[i]
            for metric_name, metric_values in trial_history.items():
                ax.plot(metric_values, label=f"Trial {trial_id}: {metric_name}")

            ax.set_title(f"Trial {trial_id}")
            ax.set_xlabel("Step")
            ax.set_ylabel("Value")
            ax.legend()

        plt.savefig(os.path.join(self.oracle._project_dir, f"best_trials_metrics_{suffix}.png"))
        plt.close()
```

I see you are using the tensorboard callback but I found it's kinda overcomplicated for a simple use case like this

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like exactly what I want. If I understand correctly this redefines keras-tuner's `RandomSearch`. However, at the moment your new `on_epoch_end`, `on_trial_end`, `plot_and_save_history` and `plot_best_trials` never get called when I use it like this. I had to change your import lines from `kerastuner` to `keras_tuner`, which suggests that we're working with different versions. Do you know how I need to change this code if the functions are someplace else now? I found `on_epoch_end` and `on_trial_end` under keras_tuner.engine.tuner, but don't know how to implement this.

Comment: Hi there, keras-tuner==1.3.5, you can check `keras_tuner.engine.tuner.Tuner` and `keras_tuner.engine.base_tuner.BaseTuner` classes for all the available/overridable methods. Just initialize the RandomSearch as usual using the wrapper I made instead of the original, when calling `tuner.search` it will run everything as usual just that for each epoch_end is going to save the metrics and when the trial ends it's going to plot them, the history and plots get saved in the `./random_search/project_name/trialXX/history.json` and `./random_search/project_name/trialXX/metrics.png`. hope it helps

Comment: There's also a fix you need to do, the tuner takes in the build_model function / hypermodel as-is `tuner = RandomSearch(build_model, ...)` when you run tuner.search it is going to populate the hyperparameter space and start calling your hypermodel with the different keras_tuner.HyperParameters inputs

Comment: You should also show minimal code for the usage of the class

Comment: I am getting error: `KeyError: '00'` in line `trial_history = self.histories[trial_id]`